# How to write a high performance web application?

Tags: web, webserver, web-frameworks

I would like to write a web app where response time is critical.

I am a bit lost with servers and web frameworks benchmarks. I see that some web frameworks offer a web server but are also sometime used with other servers like apache.

I guess that my logic should be in C++ on the server side but I have no idea what server/web framework combination to choose to query and serve the results as web pages as fast as possible.